# VBA resizes table causes a copy of data validation un the entire workbook

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I'm trying to make a resize table VBA and that one worked but when I use it it copies also the data validation in another part of the file. These are not in a table. And are copied along with along.
I think that is has someting to do with the fact that 1 table has a data validation in it.

How can I prevent this from happening?

```
Sub Resize_Table()

Dim aSheetname As Worksheet
Dim bSheetname As Worksheet
Dim cSheetname As Worksheet
Dim aaSheetname As Worksheet

Dim aTableName As String
Dim bTableName As String
Dim cTableName As String
Dim aaTableName As String

Dim aTable As ListObject
Dim bTable As ListObject
Dim cTable As ListObject
Dim aaTable As ListObject

Dim aRows As Integer
Dim bRows As Integer
Dim cRows As Integer
Dim aaRows As Integer

'Define

aTableName = "PS_Calc"
bTableName = "Prices"
cTableName = "Handling"
aaTableName = "Testing"

'Werkblad

Set aSheetname = Sheets("PS Calc")
Set bSheetname = Sheets("Prices")
Set cSheetname = Sheets("Handling")
Set aaSheetname = Sheets("Tests")

'Define tabel

Set aTable = aSheetname.ListObjects(aTableName)
Set bTable = bSheetname.ListObjects(bTableName)
Set cTable = cSheetname.ListObjects(cTableName)
Set aaTable = aaSheetname.ListObjects(aaTableName)

'Looking up rows

aRows = aTable.Range.Rows.Count
bRows = bTable.Range.Rows.Count
cRows = cTable.Range.Rows.Count
aaRows = aaTable.Range.Rows.Count

'Add how many rows

aNewRows = Worksheets("PS Calc").Range("N20")

'Resize

aTable.Resize aTable.Range.Resize(aRows + aNewRows)
bTable.Resize bTable.Range.Resize(bRows + aNewRows)
cTable.Resize cTable.Range.Resize(cRows + aNewRows)
aaTable.Resize aaTable.Range.Resize(aaRows + aNewRows)



End Sub
```

Comment: In the mean time I have tried some methods to fix this issue. Data validation only based on named range. Has no effect. Copy the data used for the validation, no effect. I have found out that it is indeed the aaTable which contains a data validation. I still cant prevent it to stop expanding the validation on other sheets which have no table but just one cell.

Comment: And the plot thickens. After checking all the data validations of the file I have found out that the only data validaions effected are the ones in the range of the added rows for example, I add 10 lines in the table the data validation is copied to 10 different cells. But when it is out of this range it works normally. What am I missing?